# Dynamically compre different rows in same SQL table

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

A customer need a tool to show customers' unsuccessful monthly payments a few months back. The starting month and the number of months back should be user-defined
all payments are recorded in the same table. 
There may or may not be payments by the same client in previous months.
It's a table with multiple rows for each payment so I will need to use group by.

I'm trying to figure out the best way to query the information.

I suppose it should be built dynamically (am I right? can this be done without dynamic sql?), and saw different approaches while searching the web:

1. dynamically add rows in the select clause, using cases, like this query: [SQL query to compare product sales by month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17194/sql-query-to-compare-product-sales-by-month)
2. dynamically add UNIONS to the same table for every month to be compared
3. dynamically add LEFT JOINS to the same table for every month to be compared

Concept code for approach 1:

```
DECLARE @month int, @monthNum int
SET @month = 103
SET @monthNum = 1

SELECT
    name,ID,Property
    ,MAX(CASE WHEN month = @month THEN month ELSE 0 END) AS month 
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN month = @month THEN paymentSum ELSE 0 END) AS paymentSum 
    ,MAX(CASE WHEN month = @month THEN PaymentFailReason ELSE 0 END) AS PaymentFailReason
    ,MAX(CASE WHEN month = @month -1 THEN month ELSE 0 END) AS monthMinusOne
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN month = @month -1 THEN paymentSum ELSE 0 END) AS paymentSumMinusOne
    ,MAX(CASE WHEN month = @month -1 THEN PaymentFailReason ELSE 0 END) AS PaymentFailReasonMinusOne

FROM
    payments

WHERE
    month BETWEEN @month -@monthNum AND @month AND status = 2

GROUP BY
name,ID,Property
```

Status = 2 means the payment was unsuccessful.

Is there a preferred solution in a case like this?

Is one approach more efficient then other?

Sample Data:

```
month   ID  name    Property    paymentSum  PaymentFailReason   Status
```

```
100      1  Aron       A            100       Has No money         2
100      2  Burt       B            100       Has No money         2
100      3  Carl       C            50        Has No money         2
101      1  Aron       A            50        Has No money         2
101      2  Burt       B            50        Has No money         2
101      3  Carl       C            50        Has No money         2
102      1  Aron       A            100       Has No money         2
102      2  Burt       B            100                            1
102      3  Carl       C            100       Has No money         2
103      1  Aron       A            102       Has No money         2
103      2  Burt       B            102       Has No money         2
103      3  Carl       C            102                            1
```

The results of querying the above data for month number 103 and 1 months back should be:

```
month   ID  name    Property    paymentSum  PaymentFailReason   Status  monthMinusOne   paymentSumMinusOne  PaymentFailReasonMinusOne
```

```
103      1  Aron        A            102       Has No money        2         102                100               Has No money
103      2  Burt        B            102       Has No money        0         102                0                 0
```

Carl payed successfuly on 103 so he's not in the results.

Burt payed successfully on 102 so his data is irrelvant for that month  (all zeros).

Edit:
I have created a dynamic SQL query that loops to create the cases for the number of months back that the users defined. takes quite a while... What am I missing? would LEFT JOINs or UNIONS be any better?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: Isn't your query already doing what you want? If not, how is it different from what you are looking for?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner I need to allow the user to choose the first month and the number of months back. Before creating a dynamic SQL procedure - I wonder what way would be the most effective to get the information, or even better - is there a way to query the data without dynamic SQL?

Comment: But the query is already complete. It expects two parameters (variables): the first month and a number of months. So have your app or Website execute the query with the two parameters.

Comment: This is just a very simple proof of concept for a given month and only one month back. the real query needs to show, for example, data for  6 or more months back, not just one. The question is if there is an **optimal** way to execute it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out myself. Hope this helps others...

Option 1 apparently works great. for some reason when I first ran it in SSMS it took more then 10 seconds for 20 months back - but that was only on the first run.

That's strange. (Maybe the server adapts after the first run?)

Since then it works really fast, less then a second for lots of months back.

here's what I did: 
(Improvments and style remarks would be greatly appreciated!)

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[CompareFailedPayments](@month int , @NumOfMonths int) 
AS

BEGIN
DECLARE @SqlHead nvarchar(max), @Sql nvarchar(max)='', @Crlf nvarchar(max), @counter int
    SET @counter = 0
    SET @Crlf = CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)

SET @SqlHead = 'DECLARE @month int = '+ CAST(@month AS VARCHAR) + @Crlf +
    'SELECT name,IDnumber,Property, ID, month, paymentsum, PaymentFailReason, EncryptedCardNum '

    SET @Sql =  'SELECT name,IDnumber,Property,Payments.ID as Id, Payments.Property as p'+ @Crlf +
    ',MAX(CASE WHEN month = @month THEN month ELSE NULL END) AS month '+ @Crlf +
    ',SUM(CASE WHEN month = @month THEN paymentsum ELSE NULL END) AS paymentsum '+ @Crlf +
    ',MAX(CASE WHEN month = @month THEN PaymentFailReason ELSE NULL END) AS PaymentFailReason '+ @Crlf +
    ',MAX(CASE WHEN month = @month THEN RIGHT(EncryptedCardNum,4) ELSE NULL END) AS EncryptedCardNum '+ @Crlf +
    'FROM Payments '+ @Crlf +
    'INNER JOIN'+ @Crlf +
    'client ON Payments.ID = client.ID'+ @Crlf +
    'WHERE (Payments.month = '+ CAST(@month AS VARCHAR) +') AND (Payments.status = 2)'+ @Crlf +
    'GROUP BY client.name, client.IDnumber, Payments.Property,Payments.ID, Payments.Property '+ @Crlf +
    ') AS Base'+ @Crlf +
    'LEFT OUTER JOIN'+ @Crlf +
    '('+ @Crlf +
    'SELECT Payments.ID as Id1, Payments.Property as p1'+ @Crlf+ @Crlf

    WHILE @counter < @NumOfMonths

        BEGIN
        SET @counter = @counter+1

        SET @Sql = @Sql+',MAX(CASE WHEN month = @month-'+CAST(@counter AS VARCHAR)+' THEN month'+' ELSE NULL END) AS month'+CAST(@counter AS VARCHAR)+ @Crlf +
        ',SUM(CASE WHEN month = @month-'+CAST(@counter AS VARCHAR)+' THEN paymentsum ELSE NULL END) AS paymentsum'+CAST(@counter AS VARCHAR)+ @Crlf +
        ',MAX(CASE WHEN month = @month-'+CAST(@counter AS VARCHAR)+' THEN PaymentFailReason ELSE NULL END) AS PaymentFailReason'+CAST(@counter AS VARCHAR)+ @Crlf +
        ',MAX(CASE WHEN month = @month-'+CAST(@counter AS VARCHAR)+' THEN RIGHT(EncryptedCardNum,4) ELSE NULL END) AS EncryptedCardNum'+CAST(@counter AS VARCHAR)+ @Crlf + @Crlf 

         SET @SqlHead = @SqlHead +', month'+CAST(@counter AS VARCHAR)+', paymentsum'+CAST(@counter AS VARCHAR)+', PaymentFailReason'+CAST(@counter AS VARCHAR)+', EncryptedCardNum'+CAST(@counter AS VARCHAR)+''

        END

     SET @SqlHead = @SqlHead +'  FROM(' + @Crlf

     SET @Sql = @Sql+
    'FROM            Payments'+ @Crlf +
    'WHERE        (Payments.month BETWEEN '+CAST(@month-@NumOfMonths AS VARCHAR)+' AND ' +CAST(@month-1 AS VARCHAR)+') AND (Payments.status = 2)'+ @Crlf +
    'GROUP BY Payments.ID, Payments.Property'+ @Crlf +
    ') AS Back '+ @Crlf +
    'ON Base.ID = Back.m1 and Base.h = Back.h1'  

--PRINT(@sqlHead+@Sql)

EXEC(@sqlHead+@Sql)
```